# Querying and aggregating nested data in mongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb

I got this type of document:

```
{
  setting: {
    team1: [{ level: 'high' }, { level: 'low' }],
    team2: [{ level: 'high' }, { level: 'medium' }, { level: 'low' }],
  }
}
```

I need to query all occurrences where `level` is 'high' and count them, over multiple documents.

Got mixed up.

How should I do it?

Comment: Can you clarify if you want to count every instance of `{level: 'high'}` or the number of documents where at least one of team1 or team2 has one `{level: 'high'}` ?

Comment: @RamitMittal the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Use aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    // reduce setting.team1 and setting.team2 to a number 1 or 0
    // based on the presence of {level: high}
    "$project": {
      "t1": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$setting.team1",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$this.level",
                  "high"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$sum": [
                  "$$value",
                  1
                ]
              },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      },
      "t2": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$setting.team2",
          "initialValue": 0,
          "in": {
            "$cond": [
              {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$this.level",
                  "high"
                ]
              },
              {
                "$sum": [
                  "$$value",
                  1
                ]
              },
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // sum t1 and t2
  {
    "$project": {
      "totalCount": {
        "$sum": [
          "$t1",
          "$t2"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  // group for count
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "highCount": {
        "$sum": "$totalCount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Link to [Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Q9DFFk-B8-w)